# appending one byte array dramatically fewer allocations than 2 byte array

Tags: go, benchmarking

According to the Go Benchmarks shown below (by running `go test -v -bench=. -benchmem`) , appending a one byte array to an array costs 1 allocation per operation.

```
Benchmark_AddOneByteArray-4              1986709           581.2 ns/op      1792 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

However, appending a 2 byte array costs 101 allocations per operation, the same as appending a 32 byte array (101 allocations)

```
Benchmark_AddTwoByteArray
Benchmark_AddTwoByteArray-4               529726          2235 ns/op        1992 B/op        101 allocs/op
Benchmark_AddThirtyTwoByteArray
Benchmark_AddThirtyTwoByteArray-4         282092          4431 ns/op        4992 B/op        101 allocs/op
```

Why does appending a one byte array cost only 1 allocation per op whereas all other sizes tested costs 101 allocations per op?

```
func addOneByteArray(n int) []any {
    my_array := make([]any, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        my_array[i] = [1]byte{}
    }
    return my_array
}
func addTwoByteArray(n int) []any {
    my_array := make([]any, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        my_array[i] = [2]byte{}
    }
    return my_array
}
func addThirtyTwoByteArray(n int) []any {
    my_array := make([]any, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        my_array[i] = [32]byte{}
    }
    return my_array
}

var N = 100
func Benchmark_AddOneByteArray(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = addOneByteArray(N)
    }
}

func Benchmark_AddTwoByteArray(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = addTwoByteArray(N)
    }
}

func Benchmark_AddThirtyTwoByteArray(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = addThirtyTwoByteArray(N)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be precise, you are setting interfaces containing arrays of different sizes into a slice. You may be observing different behaviors of the optimizer dependent on the data size.

Comment: I added `//go:noinline` above each function call. Same results

Comment: It has nothing to do with inlining. I don't know what the current strategy is, but there have been various optimization where small values are packed into an interface to avoid allocations -- this may be one of those cases. You would have to inspect the implementation to know exactly what is happening, and it is not always consistent between releases.

Comment: If you play with your values, any small integer < 256 appears to be packed into the interface, hence a single byte requires no extra allocation here.

Comment: @JimB: `// staticuint64s is used to avoid allocating in convTx for small integer values.`
`go/src/runtime/iface.go`

Comment: Inlining is only one kind of optimization, so you haven't proven that optimization is not involved by adding `//go:nolinline`.  Also, some optimizations are due to the basic go implementation and not due to optimizing the compiled code, as mentioned by @jimB .

Comment: Stop guessing and asking. Look at the generated assembly.

Comment: The question is focused on append byte arrays being expensive, but it should be focused on appending interfaces. If the slices contained the arrays explicitly, they all have the same benchmark cost.

These are allocations because every interface here is escaping to the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an optimization for interfaces, when the value can fit in the interface representation.

Normally, an interface is represented as a data block with two pointers; one is a pointer to the interface's metadata, and the other is a pointer to its value.  But when the value is no larger than a pointer, there's an optimization to fit the value in the interface block itself.

Thanks to @rocka2q and @coxley for the clues.

Note that this is an optimization in the golang runtime code, not in the compiler, so changing compiler optimization options won't make a difference.

For more information, see https://g4s8.wtf/posts/go-low-latency-one/, but note that what it says about function arguments is also true about interface variables.

Comment: Here's a link with details about this: https://research.swtch.com/interfaces#:~:text=Memory%20Optimizations

Comment: @coxley: note that particular optimization was tried and removed a long time ago, but a similar optimizations with a reduced scope were re-added a few years ago